# automate log in to a webapplication using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I am trying to automate log-in process to a web-application using `selenium` (in `chrome`). When the page is loaded there is a popup window which asks login credentials.

I have tried the following.

1. Pass the username password in the `url` - Doesnt work that way.
2. access by name that we get from the developer tool of `chrome`. -- The popup window part doesn't have a name. It is a `.swf` component where `'Allowscriptaccess'` property is set as `'sameDomain'`( I don't know whether this is relevant.) Basically that popup is a `.swf` component is what I understood.

Is there a way I can access this window and enter the login details in `selenium`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Directly submitting the form**

You're probably unable to pass the username/password in the URL due to the fact that the server-side implementation expects the `Content-Type` to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `application/json`.

Instead of using `https://mywebsite.com/login?username=myusername&password=mypassword` you probably need to use something like:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: mywebsite.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Some User Agent
Content-Length: xxx

username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

The `User-Agent` header is often necessary to not get blocked on the server side (403 Forbidden).

One way of actually checking this is to use *Firebug* or *Chrome Developer tools* to check how the login data will be sent to the server and mimic that behavior.

**Using Selenium with HTML form**

Using Selenium you can also fill in a form.

If it opens in a new window/tab/popup, you can select the right window. Assuming `driver` is the WebDriver you're using.

```java
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()); 

for (String tab : tabs) {     
    driver.switchTo().window(tab);

    // Either get it by its url
    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("https://mywebsite.com/my-login") {
        // Do the login
    }

    // Detect based on HTML on the page
    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".my-form-class #my-form-id")).size() != 0) {
        // Do the login
    }
}
```

When the login screen get loaded by JavaScript you can wait for the element to become available in the DOM. Again assuming driver is the WebDriver you're using.

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".my-form-class #my-form-id")));
```

Now you can actually fill in the form:

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".my-form-class .username")).sendKeys("your-actual-username");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".my-form-class .password")).sendKeys("your-actual-password");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".my-form-class .submit-button")).click();
```

Write code to verify a successful login.

**Interacting with Flash**

If the login is an actual Flash object, you're probably forced to use the Java [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. Thereby performing a sequence of steps:

- `mouseMove` to the location of the username/email field
- `mousePress` to click the form field
- `keyPress` to fill in you username

Repeat for password and submit button. Check if the login actually *was* successful.

Additionally you can use the [conductor](https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor) framework, which can make testing with Selenium easier.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response!

Comment: before trying out any of the options you suggested - I forgot to mention one thing here. When I try to access this particular URL via chromeDriver I am getting a page which says 'This plugin is not supported' (looks like a flash failure symol). 
If I manually access the URL it works fine for me and gives me a popup window for log in.

Comment: I cannot use Robot as my target coo-ordinates keep on changing.Its a kind of file upload on desired folders ,the position of which keeps on changing.